# Isn't this sentence grammatically inaccurate? "It changes the way their expectations about the way other people are going to treat them"

Tags: grammar

This is an excerpt from a dialogue with a psychologist Elizabeth Brondolo, PhD in APA(Link is here; https://www.apa.org/research/action/speaking-of-psychology/stress-health):

"**So when people face discrimination it changes the way their expectations about the way other people are going to treat them.**"

I believe the object of the ***verb;changes*** is '**their expectations about ~ treat them.**'

Then what does **'the way'** *that comes right after 'changes'* function here in terms of grammar? Is it an adverb? If it is, for what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The words "the way" may be safely removed from the sentence.

> "So when people face discrimination it changes their expectations about the way other people are going to treat them."

I think that the psychologist corrected herself mid-sentence:

> "So when people face discrimination it changes the way... (oops!) **their expectations about the way** other people are going to treat them."

She initially omitted "their expectations about", so she had to start again and repeat the whole phrase "their expectations about the way"

You can clearly hear at 03:25 in the record that she stops for a moment to correct the sentence.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much Cowperkettle. This sort of colloquial errors that even Native English speakers occasionally make is a beauty of learning English listening! Thank you so much for your perfectly elaborated answer. :)

Comment: From another perspective, it's a perfectly grammatical example of how people normally speak.It is not a matter of *correcting* it, it's a matter of transcribing a verbal utterance to text and analyzing it from that more familiar perspective because it's what you are more comfortable with given the way you've studied English.

Comment: I think this is well-said on this page, especially in the first comment: https://painintheenglish.com/case/479 The best way to become proficient in English is to let go of a grammatical frame because it is misleading and inadequate. Read and listen for understanding the content of messages. Studying its formal aspects will only slow you down! If you are reading or listening to things that are difficult to understand, change, if possible to simpler material. Things that genuinely interest you. For most people, this is fiction. Read or listen to things that are easy enough so that you can

Comment: process English in a state of *flow,* in which your attention is completely engaged in the communicative meaning. Things that are easy for you to understand contain deceptively immense amounts of data that we can only learn unconsciously. Grammar, as generally understood, is an illusion. Otherwise machines could be programmed to converse naturally. They are still a very long way from what our brains do in ways we still do not understand! ;)

Comment: This is simply an example of how people *normally* speak. You can say she's "correcting herself", but I suggest she is expressing herself normally and you are *mistakenly* applying a "grammar" that does not obtain! You have inadequate knowledge or reference materials to characterize spoken language. Yes, we can "safely remove" elements of her utterance, but why would you when that is how people talk? You will never be able to convert spoken language to written language in real time, and then decode it according to your notion of grammar so that you can understand it. Inefficient approach! :)

Comment: @Jin Or, speaking in terms of the grammar of the sentence rather than what was actually said, rather than removing *the way*, you can add something to the end of the sentence: *It changes the way **their expectations** [about the way other people are going to treat them]* ***will be met***.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice @JimReynolds. I'd rather work on understanding the meaning first and foremost especially in the spoken language. And I also love the concept of flow! Don't you mean the one that Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi proposed? :)

Comment: Precisely. See https://bit.ly/2ZuZcKt If your main purpose is to develop proficiency, don't stop to expend effort on understanding every element unless you are compelled to do so. Nor should you repeat something in order to *practice,* which results in little or no language acquisition. Go on to something else pleasurable. More: sdkrashen.com

Comment: Thank you @JasonBassford. Had no idea that the sentence could be made this way. :)

Comment: @JimReynolds, Oh, I'm pleased that you brought up Stephen Krashen cause I recently got to know him while reading a post about second language acquisition. Actually, I've been reading some books by him on 'FVR(Free Voluntary Reading)' as well as language learning. I'll make sure to follow the links you offered. Thank you soo much :)